# How can I pass many columns to bind_result() with more flexibility?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have some long MySQL table whose design is not totally fixed yet. So, occasionally, I need to add/delete some columns. But, every time I alter the table, I must re-write all the line dealing with bind_result(). I am looking for a solution which makes this change easy.

Assume I currently have a table with columns like col_a, col_b, col_c, ..., col_z. So, I use the bind_result() to store result values as the manual says.

```
$res = $stmt->bind_result($a, $b, $c,..., $z);
```

But, if I change the table design, I must change parameters of all the lines dealing with this bind_result() to match the new MySQL table.

Is there any technique like following?

```
// Some php file defining constants
define("_SQL_ALL_COLUMNS", "\$a, \$b, \$c, \$d, ... \$z");

// Some SQL process in in other php files
stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->bind_result(_SQL_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

So, I don't need to worry about a change of the number of the parameters in other files as long as I once define them correctly somewhere. Of course, I already found that my attempt in the previous example was not a right way.

Is there any good solution for this type of situation?

Comment: No, there's nothing built-in that does this. Maybe you should investigate using an ORM. BTW, you're missing the first argument that contains a string like `"sssiii"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) to dynamically set the number of parameters:

```
function execSQL($con, $sql, $params = null)    
    $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
    if (!$statement){
        // throw error 
        die("SQL ERROR: $sql\n $con->error");
    }

    $type = "";
    $arg = array();
    if ($params && is_array($params)){
        foreach($params as $param){
            if (is_numeric($param)){
                $type .= 'd';
                continue;
            }
            $type .= 's';
        }

        $arg[] = $type;
        foreach($params as $param){
            $arg[] = $param;
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($statement,'bind_param'), refValues($arg)); // php 7
    }
    $res = $statement->execute();

    if (!$res){
        die("Looks like the Execute Query failed.\n\nError:\n{$statement->error}\n\nQuery:\n{$sql}\n\nParams:\n{".implode(",", $arg)."}");
    }
    return $con->insert_id;
}

function refValues($arr){
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) { //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+
        $refs = array();
        foreach($arr as $key => $value){
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key];
        }
        return $refs;
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

You can use it by calling the function execSQL with an array of parameters:

```
$result = execSQL($connection,$sql,["a","b","c","..."]);
```

What this does is check the data type of the parameters and appends to the `$type` variable, which will then be passed to the bind method as first parameter.